# NameError: name <very big string> is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I am trying to enter a very long string in a list but the NameError error is showing up. I am using Spyder IDE and Python 2.7.6. Code goes like dis:

```
s=[]
s = list(raw_input())
print s
```

The input which I gave:

```
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
iymvzxcrciabvouwktzmlijjdbriaqylqmipjlilvioqyjmlenxrviaalsjokjbavjrfwcqtkhjlqxywlvoifqjrkufudiuyrmdqowjadvnvulthihsoydhkxofawzapnghdcrghotekhxurhmhhpormcwoayoqnuxtyqzhgunrdnlvuzcdorwcvvqwtgoidnbdganmxafansvjraohtljogbmzkchnqjswlfkigqlviihcivjbgtsmwengjxvziqxtvjedbpbmxioidxjksbyrimzrjvsrnrmiasocjpojxercbcmwelpozohkjbdwsphukxytmoclsvpwyeserhsqxbahcdfwuoqelrazfemyacuagoexxypuzpddulzozrvnivoozdobfibnyhmvfbrgsxlmikcjexymuncuqqxxyzkygwvoznurkgfushdwhclbrnxhgvgeusfcqaqpnnizvntnuxmbbzfsocbuxjbtbgwrgmiwbqvwdrmzqadrzilnkoikxjdapzrxobtprrowiavyaarbieovsyhrhkrymkyalrrekfaufxuhyliirzflxmchxvhlhfluzeylkygrwabwojefkktkyvtxtaiaitxjavukucdsfeotquaagtmfrfckilmsgjbghxsdcwvhalcqhctowftplxbvkpnrbqzipslroiyqvajcfcsdhnsultpvieoluotkigbyocolexojbgmlwghhbzcmdtxyhripzlpondbsdpdgysruyzdayhmdalbjejaexpskvteylkglcyhczmcztqcuegfirgmovgbqchqnrxavxjyyvczqvbmzjshbyupvasocaerrdtpaenazpzskdelmwtnwpfupxiuxonrshgunvvpkwhxzlimkdziseckemgbbtutccpqxmfkjojibtulxwwpcabgnhkobgjfjyvilcuwqdeuxbhuzdlbepkrwwhzeqfnqcybhsxzyetvhbrgeejktvdsrkrwcyltblwkewjcadzjgqpmwaxswckppbnrazmdmjnqfyuhdvsjnhwkjvcfxmvopiirjuuwfjomiltlinxwutieqklpyieptmheidcoptazewkojjkgcsmuezkeiqubedfmiicxbdwhbjvmsiuxcgrhgbnqtjtxmakvioulrruuashscbrekjnsmbigkddzdpwoeqbxhwsjqbesevyqemitnszzvcyzuwpynqvuopgeskyzhxpojyhysgzqkarewgejwcglrmrmyqlhpavyacytixjtzazwiehegnrzbjlbbyjqzeqzhqurpfmphmnpquwyinxlylnbjyrkejmnzgfrorgvftnxnjvxyvlxgayrysccbosdwxukqciwxvvmgrmeoxduxelxypbbdtgasamjewhbrcqzvcgjzlfyrtvpiyrmszokacvgzckshasecaoblvbdoyuxwllqlbbndyvedfxkfrqjremecnhqlcnkpaacbdrfcnjfuirczhlsoyxqnegziwlawlcypwfrlqyfzpjywvrkvociujjffwfdijbxhiqszoaydjwbgpodfqocbzhiwomexpdfytzxhzxmlvptldxswluxkdgirumrjryjkxitzfhkbxdocagyndyaggiaaxrlopxbofunlczobdcdfkcvpcvyifyicrvtgsuwyoklslbtofxwpbrhdmflrdvwuspcllylzkyuwznmemivnbcqnjdhmafitwmehnrizpcvqskuguruwwmlfsuuszelxrreekpdztbrnnnuhfofdcrkulennlakcurieglgzoxpbljlsxqvbhhwvoliznsbhllorwutntiqerbyquvrddpyrciqqbtzoengcjbrdjijcliuffnjifjbhsrzvmbjqqpvasmdduofiwbnepymuiodahfvugemwwjwowbssqzaobqssohoyxryewvaecpdayboudipvkplnfgfwntukkvqjstpuisuiulfzvuuflhstnzpaslmfgfozyfviysssdxrarnifuayiapkuaxzjepkcvfmtxenceedxtlcnnavppgksflbjblnysbtshgulmzjfmlsaoqrdydxfpyosldqegjwnrsbdskiexcglsarsdoxspnmaqceyncmevnhpzrtwuckocdhhtecksolktrjguvlrkugjmbhidtwhydpsiteahpkajvjfqwwcqclefvmlqlspojjwenymfloogxtzvrbovpsamhlcsgtircfwsfkxsynbygatzdhuscwglijdqcnhhsfzapwuqjvorvjsztmtxkaislnkpauwvzxxpvrhgnvxigrjzffwqhgkstvjupirqfohbfohsjhdsamrgrqwawgsqdemumdltrswwhersnukngetaurasavidbwanzlisffrojijycvnkzhkvanoaiyglvgywtgrynipyqywsvkevtpsteiwohczekxcdftbvbsttqqnmcsjxjdsnmobvsabczdfgzjbcbvwunlirdromuibixcdregwdkbklmnnokjkxvsoalephnqqmtvfzcbdodpzremhpyrmvjdvwjkewdwkyrqxvralwrkowzvlznzuycrvoebkhxxfqneoehzdymrwnohmbjicnzzbdammzjtpyyfeffhftycgnlsquauiztjfvxtwinogntlsyuzrtbzinrajtvtvqdaoctkniytvugpsbrmwslghfgtybmturviuruhzvcxplojofxmalsjqycqcrkwihgeycnaxszmdpytvvfxiziyzlrbebzmihrjkejhwiwbzwwwtdtcccacprfvufhfoyqyfzidjghicdfvjazlecpvvvqqcaxqanrfozlxfshjxoggrguxiltdilvmlufmhwtvveucyenwuvelbajloerwpmlbhqpqmimjninloajjvqwzsfkgjbfbqqezgtpubddqoqecqnnnfkoapbibepeufitnblheomveczhuoukugywyzezewfadnwrqhauxnpcrolmdhyzowvmwbncxscbhyuxfwrflhhdxurabpzrlwdjasnxkqarouqwtidermhogarhpsbdpeorxcqjsrdintggdjlwvulbvelkwmpnseergvbaoeibzpkfavbwrmzmsmzpaocvsjmagpauvlvvcfaccbauqcgiqhztweoqncrtstnnekkgsmjuqlqgnzqegqxcunvjpoejhrxmdjsvwdqopgwehmioehsawnlobpxliwxmgrjexbsmkoqrcbfhkyjhnvvrkucvrbhxuqdrsvdclwtnzbwjzgsodpfnkjkbkrafkdweycilydyxevifdbugqbvclgdxxdcjibnidxtdbschpkpsnjygmtixzmvzrziacyifvekywoilbxdoidwuwfuwtrvmqdmtdxabbnzzbhmcgrtoupjqudmpwjcmpqhspktsxvraefdlwyzqnkjkpxzlhdayuhqjrmcqjvrnbwazuashmdtcatnjwnhsxacqoghxdamgwpgqpazddtffovpmiyhfalworfnufcdbrltilulqnrvdmmswlzelkccdhpzorcrinkqaeequxmzjyrhlqlxcpbfwqfmkjduxnnxurqoocpzchiozuncjojigqusaanznayjtozjqpivwsjxoyzamliubenbeacucbdxpfgiuqdsimpxkpxychudlhhsjjonktkcyqksgnkrbaonrllvuhyhphzarnodjyhhprcxgmohoeuhrhclpdtgksgdiwjtvqamicjqrayfeupwerhvucbhxjkfgtydmapwdamwakbhhqflkoigrjpouavcvvfjvufaxswzeagnsnyecglvrajoceqabyjyurzrjxrpxzdsndwrmjmdmvtobmqekccetbwcbnraowsbarsmagrmblbextihvlnoojsrymsnimqidlweroqvbtzankhkxuzlgtdefxtojkynvvrmljhofjoutxesrfdzzigefzurjtegqxtdgcrllffgcmyvrevqobxwcrnmktscsnfysymfftohhofzscrjfohhgwvspqvhfchxbvdgrrqyfxzazrjehsnnojidbdmghvekrhtkajifikhhbsnkkayylgbmlptslxfegyoijynrixylpnwanwyzecnprgjefoinowvxvlodiorxbnzrlyspcfetopyvgijufgucrkhbbybenavyapncvtyljygrgpnnyhpruxvvvwzjyvjbkxfhqdsbdbsmsizqppilodgjbgubdecpdiztntxturfnzefrvncjsjvvrrxuxblalkwzetuakznkfvbbkfmdohafbxbyznbkxxldqhecgtmmoppzvbelletmeumdjnpjkdmcksftmthalybgbftmmmaqjnvscmbnpqrciyxusgxdealfiguutwkcjfwotydlqunytmvnsusyudfcjzyewiihpfvjfyuvvjvoxqdrkvphywjjykouswdkdbtibpfwabmxrpoekflibwuzgkvbgblmcgudxccxdowwemcorpzuotwwftxlukzwswcpyeodukbyweppvokjjigobfbwqdukzyaxeqazddzbhordedoplufoajmsmhclheimvknynmzxbschvqxincxnllhxsjicosoleblspmrqfvyclvnazmnlxuksgtuunkhslsmaedtlatqlqdmppbcoyngeiaaxkjpxbbahgvvgolueqivhlavlpcrxetwrcmofpqpwlkebxahnkduyfrjutbtauprzbheratplfvncyupizliedsyyvtypjrqmbvdbquowsdyqaqabbjggbgfyafplzgxcbdfrxtnrzohbekchtkowttuvajgzpdbsigmgcbzdphetrgbmtrimkejkppkfunzdwllynkbetfamndyiuiweofqewcltqkymwjmlvnprupdjsesmoqsfwjjulundelpcwbnuqflkuqwpwqblguqefbbqvoubclgaptwhahuvaqkwgnjojztoauhxkdboohrfcnndxhazzkvfzfvlgozjkiixljncqejtuwyrfyqeknljshwbxwkigshseuwuzfptepmjneqxrbjmkfpidzqktzeztcushlnnbbzqfpozszndeclkddwycayveuqlfdbifazmpplhoykucxefaaecccagwqudtvoavpnmeyvuziobfvjivnkarmgpcaswxgwuvlgbmevlmkotfxbcmocdajsdllbjtzdrlmuxqqkecyxjybnkrqotbiwotzzpbfimrcljuxpwxofvpviilwcoeacaccrdhzradclybauyocwgxeqkasygtaixezanarngvyewaawresxdwnnyinhdqrauraitrxzoyfmygipmdoqzefamtjrjarfttppmpoanwmnewfqztgbzmblhmeqmvxgonvaclcrhqennjemfkneyqsfcwxpuvxkkunohpfrgletxifcvvitlazozwfvtcfdysrfkywskbnhjuleptabwzrvxwqtaxyyqsdcqcucdhlobwvtsvuowljtjbojynhqfmsxooatxnizkdueyqsubdpmeevetevaqpxfezabniczlydlovfpaxdedykwcfwtxvadvaekljjwhokwlrnlorrtrbrujppglrjitpseaddktngegvpvoiqijicsxtykkhufzokzrnjmcrqiphffpwnbgrtfksswbmcabocudlhffzpujxzatnbbevirpapsptvqhxmkkvrpxjjiglibymcejkxannscinsqmgcxcwobfajlltmlfqroap
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You have a line break in your input, which is causing this problem.

Comment: I suppose you had `list(input())` earlier. Are you sure you have saved the program after the change to `raw_input()` before trying?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using raw_input, somehow. You'd get a string. What you're describing makes it sounds like your `<very big string>` is actually an undefined variable name passed in to `list()`.

Comment: You need to remove your line break.

Comment: @kvivek Actually when I am trying to paste this whole string in the console then its creating error while if I am pasting it inside the code(assigning it to "s")with the "/" line break then output is fine!

Comment: Guys, one more question. I am trying to solve a problem in hackerrank in which one of the test cases had this particular string which was passed in the `list s`. So I want to ask that, if that string which was passed had a line break then how could I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gust guessing, but I think the thing with the line break is it - if we do it interactively.

So we sit there, staring at the `>>>`, and enter the code above.

At the end, it looks like

```
>>> s = list(raw_input())
print s
>>> s
['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', ' ', 's']
>>>
```

If I enter the two strings now, the interpreter will complain about them.

If I put this into a script or function, I get

```
>>> def f():
...     return list(raw_input())
...
>>>
>>> f()
(Here I paste both lines from above. Only the frist gets read, however. The following is the output I get:)
['a', 'd', 'r', 'd', 'w', 'v', 'd', 'z', 'h', 's', 'h', 'k', 'v', 'z', 'r', 'b', 'x', 'q', 'd', 't', 'b', 'r', 'v', 'y', 'r', 'g', 'v', 'y', 'a', 'f', 'y', 'a', 'i', 'p', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'u',
[...]
'n', 'g', 'd', 'm', 'q', 'y', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'q', 'p', 'h', 'g', 'g']
(Now comes the command prompt again, which gets the 2nd line, which I abbreviate here:)
>>> iymvzxcrciabvo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'iymvzxcrciabvo' is not defined
```

As said, it is just a guess, based on the few informations you give us about what exactly you do and which error message you exactly get, resp. which of the two strings is indeed contained in the traceback.